# RKHS norm and $L_\infty$ norm under Gaussian kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Given a gaussian kernel $k(x) = \exp(-||x||^2/2)$, let $H_k$ be the associated Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space(RKHS). My question would be: is it possible to obtain an upper bound of $||f||_{H_k}$ in terms of $||f||_{L_\infty}$ for any $f \in H_k$? The other direction seems to be easy.

Comment: It's unlikely that a useful bound exists. The RKHS norm measures smoothness, but there are of course very unsmooth functions with low $L_\infty$ norm

Answer (score 0):

Under no further assumptions on $f$, I'd say that such an upper bound is unlikely. For instance, the Gaussian kernel's RKHS does not contain constants, other than the zero function (see Corollary 4.44 in Steinwart & Christmann, 2008, for a proof). Then any function approaching a constant $c > 0$ everywhere would have $\lVert f \rVert_{L_\infty} \to c$, but $\lVert f \rVert_{H_k} \to \infty$. It might be possible to establish an upper bound on the RKHS norm based on additional assumptions, though. One thing that might help is that the eigenvalue decay of the Gaussian kernel is well understood (see Belkin, 2008).

References:

- Belkin, M. (2018). Approximation beats concentration? An approximation view  on inference with smooth radial kernels. *Proceedings of the 31st  Conference On Learning Theory*, in *Proceedings of Machine Learning Research* 75:1348-1361 Available from https://proceedings.mlr.press/v75/belkin18a.html.
- Steinwart, I., & Christmann, A. (2008). Kernels and Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces. In Support Vector Machines (pp. 110–163). Springer. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-77242-4_4